# Issue with form submission - Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, forms, form-submit

I am experiencing an issue with submitting a form on my website. When I fill out the form and click the submit button, nothing happens and I do not see any network requests in the browser console.

The form is supposed to submit to the URL https://example.com/, but it seems that the form is not able to send a POST request to this URL.

I have checked the JavaScript console and there are no error messages, and I have also verified that the form fields have the correct names and that the submit button has the correct type.

I am using a shared hosting plan with PHP 7.3.33, and my website was built with WordPress. Recently, I decided to change the design of my website and I did it with Node.js v18.14.0.

I followed the advice of technical support, and I deployed the app to the server. using the application manager.

Now, the technical support answered me this: "What I can confirm is that it's making a successful POST request to "/" (e.g the same page), however there are no errors". But there is no post at the console, and the message I get always is: "Error al enviar el formulario" (error sending form).

This is my js and form:

```js
const form = document.querySelector('#form');
const spinner = document.querySelector('#spinner');
const formMessage = document.querySelector('#form-message');

form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  spinner.style.display = 'block';
  formMessage.style.display = 'none';
  const formData = new FormData(form);
  fetch('/', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData
  })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      spinner.style.display = 'none';
      formMessage.style.display = 'block';
      formMessage.textContent = data.message;
      form.reset();
    })
    .catch(error => {
      spinner.style.display = 'none';
      formMessage.style.display = 'block';
      formMessage.textContent = 'Error al enviar el formulario.';
    });
});
```

```html
<form method="post" action="/" id="form">
                        <div class="row gtr-uniform">
                            <div class="col-6 col-12-xsmall"><input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Nombre" /></div>
                            <div class="col-6 col-12-xsmall"><input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" /></div>
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <select id="type" name="type">
                                    <option value="" selected>Selecciona Tipo</option>
                                  </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <select id="make" name="make" disabled>
                                    <option value="" selected>Selecciona Marca</option>
                                  </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <select id="model" name="model" disabled>
                                    <option value="" selected>Selecciona Modelo</option>
                                  </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <select id="year" name="year" disabled>
                                    <option value="" selected>Selecciona Año</option>
                                  </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12"><textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Tu mensaje" rows="4"></textarea></div>
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <ul class="actions special">
                                    <li><input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="primary" /></li>
                                </ul>
                                <div id="spinner" style="display: none;">
                                <svg class="spinner" width="65px" height="65px" viewBox="0 0 66 66" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                    <circle class="path" fill="none" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round" cx="33" cy="33" r="30"></circle>
                                 </svg></div>
                                <span id="form-message" style="display: none;">Consulta enviada con éxito</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

And this is my backend in Node.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const sanitizer = require('sanitizer');
const rateLimit = require("express-rate-limit");

const app = express();

app.use('/assets', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'assets'), {
    setHeaders: function (res) {
      res.set('Content-Type', 'text/css');
    }
  }));

app.use('/images', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'images'), {
    setHeaders: function (res, path) {
      if (path.endsWith('.jpg')) {
        res.set('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');
      } else if (path.endsWith('.png')) {
        res.set('Content-Type', 'image/png');
      }
    }
  }));

app.use('/assets/css/images', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'assets/css/images')));


app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// create a rate limiter middleware
const submissionLimiter = rateLimit({
  windowMs: 15 * 60 * 1000, // 15 minutes
  max: 100, // limit each IP to 100 requests per windowMs
  message: "Too many submissions from this IP, please try again later"
});
// apply the rate limiter middleware to the / endpoint
app.use('/', submissionLimiter);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  const name = sanitizer.sanitize(req.body.name);
  const email = sanitizer.sanitize(req.body.email);
  const type = sanitizer.sanitize(req.body.type) || 'No especifica';
  const make = sanitizer.sanitize(req.body.make) || 'No especifica';
  const model = sanitizer.sanitize(req.body.model) || 'No especifica';
  const year = sanitizer.sanitize(req.body.year) || 'No especifica';
  const message = sanitizer.sanitize(req.body.message);

  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'hydra.vivawebhost.com',
    port: 995,
    auth: {
      user: 'info@calverasparts.com',
      pass: 'Diplodocus1986!'
    }
  });

  const mailOptions = {
    from: 'calverasparts@gmail.com',
    to: 'info@calverasparts.com',
    subject: 'Nueva Consulta',
    text: `Recibiste una nueva consulta. Nombre: ${name}. Email: ${email}. Tipo: ${type}. Marca: ${make}. Modelo: ${model}. Año: ${year}. Mensaje: ${message}.`
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(500).json({ status: 'error', message: 'Error al enviar el correo' });
    } else {
      console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
      res.status(200).json({ status: 'success', message: 'Consulta enviada con éxito' });
    }
  });
});
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`); // Add this line
app.listen(port, () => {
console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});
```

I really don't know where is the problem.

Thank you for your help.

Best regards.

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't add tags. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

change the URL in the JavaScript code to match the correct URL that the form should be submitted to.

In your JavaScript code, change this line:

```
fetch('/', {})
```

To:

```
fetch('https://example.com/', {})
```